# Use dragend.js to swipe horizontal and vertical

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slider, swipe

I would like to use [dragend.js](http://stereobit.github.io/dragend/) to combine a swipe function horizontal and vertical.

This is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6d6LH/

```
$(function () {
    new Dragend($("#demo").get(0), {
        afterInitialize: function () {
            $("#demo").css("visibility", "visible");
        }
    });
});
```

How I can do this?

Otherwise would it be possible to scroll the page vertical? Currently it's only possible with 2 fingers.